# In React, my uncontrolled radio group triggers form's onChange only once per radio element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**EDIT:** This is actually a bug in React. It affects React 15.6.1 but *not* React 15.1.0. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10078

I'm attaching a `change` event listener to my parent `form` element, which contains thee uncontrolled `input type="radio"` elements. I expect the form's `change` event listener to be invoked every time one of the radio options is selected.

Instead, the listener gets invoked *only once* for each individual radio option. Any subsequent changes to the radio options, while visible in the browser, do not trigger the `change` event.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a Codepen that demonstrates this in the console: https://codepen.io/yeahjohnnn/pen/yoxqpL

And here's the code:

```
class MyExample extends React.Component {
  handleFormChange(event) {
    console.log('Form change. Value: ', event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onChange={this.handleFormChange}>
        <label>
          Text
            <input type="text" name="textbox-field" />
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" value="a" /> A
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" value="b" /> B
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" value="c" /> C
        </label>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user. **Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value**.

Read more on [MDN Web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change)

It's more reliable to use `Click` events in this case.

Attach an `onClick` listener to each of the radio buttons. Like this:

```
class MyExample extends React.Component {
  handleFormChange(event) {
    console.log('Form change. Value: ', event.target.value);
}

render() {
  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        Text
        <input type="text" name="textbox-field" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" value="a" 
          onClick={this.handleFormChange}/> A
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" value="b" 
          onClick={this.handleFormChange}/> B
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" value="c" 
          onClick={this.handleFormChange}/> C
      </label>
    </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyExample />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

You can open DevTools to see that the value changes every time you click a radio button.

Comment: It works, but your answer doesn't explain why `onChange` behaves like that on form.

Comment: This doesn't work for my needs because you are handling click events on the input elements directly. I need to the change even to bubble to my form.

Answer (score 1):

Your form doesn't receive the change event because the checked attribute of a radio isn't changed (or React doesn't know when that value is changed).
The correct approach would be we handle the selected value of radio button then passing that value to `checked` prop of radio button.

My code:

```
const RadioButton = ({ onChange, value, checked, text }) => (
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" value={value} onChange={onChange} checked={checked} /> {text}
  </label>
);

const RadioGroup = ({ onChange, value, options }) => (
  <div>
    {options.map(option => (
      <RadioButton {...option} checked={option.value === value} onChange={onChange} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

class MyExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedRadio: null,
    };
    this.onRadioChange = this.onRadioChange.bind(this);
  }

  onRadioChange(event) {
    this.setState({ selectedRadio: event.target.value });
  }

  handleFormChange(event) {
    console.log('Form change. Value: ', event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onChange={this.handleFormChange}>
        <label>
          Text
            <input type="text" name="textbox-field" />
        </label>
        <RadioGroup
          value={this.state.selectedRadio}
          onChange={this.onRadioChange}
          options={[
            { value: 'a', text: 'A' },
            { value: 'b', text: 'B' },
            { value: 'c', text: 'C' },
          ]}
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyExample />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here is the full code https://codepen.io/phthhieu/pen/BdOPge

Comment: This doesn't work for my needs because you are using controlled inputs. I may have to give in and implement something like this, but I would really like for the change event to bubble from my uncontrolled radio buttons.